# PHP Error, Unexpected Ending. Functions.php file

Tags: php, html, function

I keep getting some sort of Syntax error. It says:

> [09-Jan-2013 04:17:17 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in functions.php on line 730

I have removed the ',' but then I get another error which says unexpected ')', then unexpected ';) and finally unexpected '$end'

Anyone have any idea what I'm not doing?

```
/*----------------------------------------/
            POST LIST THUMBS
/----------------------------------------*/
if ( !function_exists('fb_AddThumbColumn') && function_exists('add_theme_support') ) {

    function fb_AddThumbColumn($cols) {
        $cols['thumbnail'] = __('Thumbnail');
        return $cols;
    }
    function fb_AddThumbValue($column_name, $post_id) {
        $width = (int) 45;
        $height = (int) 45;
        if ( 'thumbnail' == $column_name ) {
            // thumbnail of WP 2.9
            $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true );
            // image from gallery
            $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image') );
            if ($thumbnail_id)
                $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, array($width, $height), true );
            elseif ($attachments) {
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
                    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, array($width, $height), true );
                }
            }
            if ( isset($thumb) && $thumb ) {
                echo $thumb;
            } else {
                echo __('None');
            }
        }
    }
    // for posts
    add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'fb_AddThumbColumn' );
    add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'fb_AddThumbValue', 10, 2 );
    // for pages
    //add_filter( 'manage_pages_columns', 'fb_AddThumbColumn' );
    //add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column', 'fb_AddThumbValue', 10, 2 );
}, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . );


//------ SIDEBARS ------//
//require_once(LN_FRAMEWORK .
```

Comment: What is with the `}, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . );` line?

Comment: This is line 730:

}, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . );

Comment: You need to check code before posting if something is cut-out. If everything is ok then it is clear that `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .` AND `require_once(LN_FRAMEWORK .` will clearly generate errors. Also It should be hinted that what code is at line number 730.

Comment: In case of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .` ending dot should be removed.

Comment: That line is syntactically incorrect. Replace it with a `}`. I'm also assuming the sidebars portion has more code in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a `}` somewhere. Make sure you're using a code editor with syntax highlighting and bracket matching, and use it to check your brackets.

Comment: Hi, I looked around. I am using Sublime for my editor. There seems to be no missing } =[

Answer (score 0):

//------ SIDEBARS ------//

`require_once(LN_FRAMEWORK)` in your code you are missing `)`. ( and ) <-- they need to match

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once(LN_FRAMEWORK .
```

should be

```
require_once(LN_FRAMEWORK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line:

```
}, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . );
```

That whole line is wrong. In several ways. It looks like it's a chunk of code that's been pasted into the wrong place by accident.

Do you know what it's supposed to be doing? If not, drop the whole line and just leave the `}` there.